# going from heirarchical XML to heirarchical SQL tables then SQL to c# objects to go to user view, how should I store the data in the databases?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, best-practices, xml, c#

Hi I'm getting my data from a web service using their getData call and it comes in as fairly chunky heirarchical XML, first everything all at once, like

```
<allData>
 <product1>
  <property1>
     <subProperty1>
     </subProperty1>
     [...other sub properties]
  </property1>
 <product1>

[...product2, product3,]

</allData>
```

Update/ picture for question clarity (Flow I am concerned with now is Right to Left):

[image: Flow from Web Service to User]

Is this a good way to do it?  So we have XML Data coming externally, deserialize it into C# Objects in our Server app,  then I have to make a choice of how to store it on the SQL Database...
Should I use Varbinary Data type?   Then Deserialize it when updates occur in the User APPS?

Update:
For now I will use XML as my message payload to make it easier to read when debugging and testing, then when the project is just nearing completion, I will try to switch it to binary and marshal/ un-marshal data on both sides as I think there may be some performance advantages to this.

Comment: Get away from XML as soon as your start transporting from C# to the DB (database cycles are expensive)... Do you need to query by the hierarchy? i.e. will you need to write queries like: "Find all records below this level in the hierarchy"

Comment: Also, does the external web service have flexible schema or not?

Comment: I won't query by hierarchy I think in the database, any inner queries will be done on the user app or server app level where the XML would be turned into c#objects.  the external web service accepts and returns XML with specific structures only (not very flexible) and validates at the web service level by checking existence of data in certain child nodes.